# какой возвращаемый тип задать для функции которая возвращает Promise.all

Tags: javascript, typescript

вот функция где надо указать возвращаемый тип

```
export const getDashboard = (date: TRange): any => {
    return Promise.all([
        StatisticService.getCustomerChart(date),
        StatisticService.getOrderChart(date),
        StatisticService.getPartnerChart(date),
        StatisticService.getWorkerChart(date),
    ])
};
```

вот класс у которого берутся методы

```
export class StatisticService {

    static getCustomerChart(date: TRange): TResponseMany<IStatistic> {
        const queryParams = getQueryParams(date);

        return customFetch(URLS.STATISTICS.CUSTOMER, queryParams);
    }

    static getOrderChart(date: TRange): TResponseMany<IStatistic> {
        const queryParams = getQueryParams(date);

        return customFetch(URLS.STATISTICS.ORDER, queryParams);
    }

    static getPartnerChart(date: TRange): TResponseMany<IStatistic> {
        const queryParams = getQueryParams(date);

        return customFetch(URLS.STATISTICS.PARTNER, queryParams);
    }

    static getWorkerChart(date: TRange): TResponseMany<IStatistic> {
        const queryParams = getQueryParams(date);

        return customFetch(URLS.STATISTICS.WORKER, queryParams);
    }
}
```

и еще интерфейсы

```
interface IResponseMany<T> extends IResponseDetails {
    body: T[];
}

export type TResponseMany<T> = Promise<IResponseMany<T>>;

export interface IStatistic {
    creationDate: string;
    count: number;
}
```

Comment: `Promise<any[]>`

Comment: @entithat Promise<any> ? нельзя как то точную типизацию дать? Promise<IStatistic> что то типо этого

Comment: Посмотреть что реально возвращает Promise.all в файле `typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts`. А это может быть примерно такое `Promise<[T1, T2, ...]>`. Т.е. для каждого элемента массива свой тип.

Comment: ваш промис.олл вернет массив из значений тех решённых промиссов..

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg я пробовал сделать так Promise<[TResponseMany<IStatistic>,TResponseMany<IStatistic>,...]> не работает

Comment: все спасибо всем разобрался

Comment: лайфхак. если не знаешь какой тип вернуть - не пиши ничего. потом вызови свою функцию и результат сохрани в переменную. наведи курсор на переменную и IDE подскажет тебе какой она имеет тип. Можешь смело его писать в качестве возвращаемого значения :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип возвращаемый [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), соответствует массиву, элементами которого являются значения переданных `Promise`.

В данном случае все функции возвращают `Prommise<IResponseMany<T>>`, следовательно тип возвращаемого значения будет `Promise<IResponseMany<T>[]>`